# Generic Stack Data Structure Using Linked Lists Follow Up

Tags: c++, linked-list

I made a post that follows from this [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/197174/generic-stack-data-structure-using-linked-lists/197180?noredirect=1#comment380142_197180). I made most of changes that I could understand from the following link, and here is now an update to that original post. I just want to see if there is any major changes that I need to consider making and perhaps to gain some more insight into how to achieve making those changes.

Here is the header file:

```
#ifndef Stack_h
#define Stack_h

template <class T>
class Stack {
private:
    struct Node {
        T data;
        Node* next;
    };
    Node* _top;

    // Used for destructor to delete elements
    void do_unchecked_pop();

    // Use for debugging purposes and for overloading the << operator
    void show(std::ostream &str) const;


public:
    // Rule of 5
    Stack() : _top(nullptr){}                                                 // empty constructor
    Stack<T>(Stack<T> const& value);                                          // copy constructor
    Stack<T>(Stack<T>&& move) noexcept;                                       // move constuctor
    Stack<T>& operator=(Stack&& move) noexcept;                               // move assignment operator
    ~Stack();                                                                 // destructor

    // Overload operators
    Stack& operator=(Stack const& rhs);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str, Stack<T> const& data) {
        data.show(str);
        return str;
    }

    // Member functions
    void swap(Stack& other) noexcept;
    bool empty() const;
    int size() const;
    void push(const T& theData);
    void push(T&& theData);
    T& top() const;
    void pop();

};

template <class T>
Stack<T>::Stack(Stack<T> const& value) : _top(nullptr) {
    for(Node* loop = value._top; loop != nullptr; loop = loop->next) {
        push(loop->data);
    }
}

template <class T>
Stack<T>::Stack(Stack<T>&& move) noexcept : _top(nullptr) {
    move.swap(*this);
}

template <class T>
Stack<T>& Stack<T>::operator=(Stack<T> &&move) noexcept {
    move.swap(*this);
    return *this;
}

template <class T>
Stack<T>::~Stack() {
    while(_top != nullptr) {
        do_unchecked_pop();
    }
}

template <class T>
Stack<T>& Stack<T>::operator=(Stack const& rhs) {
    Stack copy(rhs);
    swap(copy);
    return *this;
}


template <class T>
void Stack<T>::swap(Stack<T> &other) noexcept {
    using std::swap;
    swap(_top,other.top);
}

template <class T>
bool Stack<T>::empty() const {
    return _top == nullptr;
}

template <class T>
int Stack<T>::size() const {
    int size = 0;
    Node* current = _top;
    while(current != nullptr) {
        size++;
        current = current->next;
    }
    return size;
}

template <class T>
void Stack<T>::push(const T &theData) {
    Node* newNode = new Node;
    newNode->data = theData;
    newNode->next = nullptr;

    if(_top != nullptr) {
        newNode->next = _top;
    }
    _top = newNode;
}

template <class T>
void Stack<T>::push(T&& theData) {
    Node* newNode = new Node;
    newNode->data = std::move(theData);
    newNode->next = nullptr;

    if(_top != nullptr) {
        newNode->next = _top;
    }
    _top = newNode;
}

template <class T>
T& Stack<T>::top() const {
    return _top->data;
}

template <class T>
void Stack<T>::do_unchecked_pop() {
    Node* tmp = _top->next;
    delete _top;
    _top = tmp;
}

template <class T>
void Stack<T>::pop() {
    if(_top == nullptr) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("the Stack is empty!");
    }
    do_unchecked_pop();
}

template <class T>
void Stack<T>::show(std::ostream &str) const {
    for(Node* loop = _top; loop != nullptr; loop = loop->next) {
        str << loop->data << "\t";
    }
    str << "\n";
}


#endif /* Stack_h */
```

Here is the main.cpp file that tests the latter:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include "Stack.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {



    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////// Stack Using Linked List //////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    Stack<int> obj;
    obj.push(2);
    obj.push(4);
    obj.push(6);
    obj.push(8);
    obj.push(10);
    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout<<"---------------Displaying Stack Contents---------------";
    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout << obj << std::endl;

    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout<<"---------------Pop Stack Element -------------------";
    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    obj.pop();
    std::cout << obj << std::endl;

    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout<<"---------------Get the size of stack -------------------";
    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout << obj.size() << std::endl;

    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout<<"---------------Re-Add Poped Element---------------";
    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    obj.push(10);
    std::cout << obj << std::endl;

    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout<<"---------------Print top element --------------------";
    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout << obj.top() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you so opposed to having a `Node` constructor?

Comment: @vnp I am not at all, just not understanding why and how I would go about changing my code. More so the why factor, I would of course figure it out in terms of coding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

((Note: the code changed while I was writing this review, so it might not match exactly.))

Pretty decent code! There are only a few trouble spots.

I'd start by suggesting that you add the necessary includes to the header file. For example, the class needs `std::ostream` for the insertion operator, so you should `#include <iosfwd>`. And so on for all the other standard library stuff you need. (Your code only works for now because `main.cpp` includes headers that satisfy all the requirements before including `Stack.h`.)

```
struct Node {
    T data;
    Node* next;
};
Node* _top;
```

You should take advantage of in-class initializers - it will simplify the code, and make it safer. In this case, both `next` and `_top` could have `= nullptr`.

I see comments suggesting you add a constructor to `Node`, but you don't need one. I wouldn't bother with it.

```
Stack() : _top(nullptr){}
```

You should always prefer to use `= default` rather than `{}` when defining things that can be implicitly generated, and the implicitly generated versions do the right thing. If you also use an in-class initializer to define `Node* _top = nullptr;`, then this becomes:

```
Stack() = default;
```

And you can even add `constexpr` and `noexcept`.

Speaking of `noexcept`, there are a couple of other places it might be applicable - at the very least `empty()` and `size()` seem like no-fail functions. You can probably make a fair bit of it `constexpr`, too, but that's less important because `Stack` doesn't seem like a compile-time type.

```
Stack<T>(Stack<T> const& value);
```

You don't really need the `<T>`s inside the class body. And you shouldn't include them, because it may cause headaches if you change the template parameters.

```
template <class T>
Stack<T>::Stack(Stack<T> const& value) : _top(nullptr) {
    for(Node* loop = value._top; loop != nullptr; loop = loop->next) {
        push(loop->data);
    }
}
```

This function will leak memory if it fails. Imagine what would happen if you were copying a 100 element stack, and `push()` failed on element 99. All those other nodes would never be deallocated.

If you're not going to use smart pointers (which makes sense in this context), then you'll need to use an explicit `try`-`catch`, maybe something like this:

```
template <class T>
Stack<T>::Stack(Stack<T> const& value) {
    try {
        for(auto loop = value._top; loop != nullptr; loop = loop->next)
            push(loop->data);
    }
    catch (...) {
        while(_top != nullptr)
            do_unchecked_pop();
        throw;
    }
}
```

Moving on down:

```
template <class T>
void Stack<T>::swap(Stack<T> &other) noexcept {
    using std::swap;
    swap(_top,other.top);
}
```

There appears to be a typo here - it should probably be `other._top`. If you're going to define a `swap()` member function, you might as well define a free `swap()` function as well.

```
template <class T>
int Stack<T>::size() const {
    int size = 0;
    Node* current = _top;
    while(current != nullptr) {
        size++;
        current = current->next;
    }
    return size;
}
```

You can simplify this quite a bit with a `for` loop:

```
template <class T>
int Stack<T>::size() const {
    int size = 0;
    for (auto curent = _top; current != nullptr; current = current->next)
        size++;
    return size;
}
```

On to the `push()` functions:

```
template <class T>
void Stack<T>::push(const T &theData) {
    Node* newNode = new Node;
    newNode->data = theData;
    newNode->next = nullptr;

    if(_top != nullptr) {
        newNode->next = _top;
    }
    _top = newNode;
}
```

In this function, you create a `Node` with `data` default constructed, and then copy `theData`. That is inefficient, and may even not work for types that don't have a default constructor. Instead you should do:

```
template <class T>
void Stack<T>::push(const T &theData) {
    auto newNode = new Node{theData};

    if(_top != nullptr) {
        newNode->next = _top;
    }
    _top = newNode;
}
```

If you aren't going to use an in-class initializer for `Node::next`, then you'll need to write: `auto newNode = new Node{theData, nullptr};`.

Same idea for `push(T&&)`.

```
template <class T>
T& Stack<T>::top() const {
    return _top->data;
}
```

If the stack is empty, this function will cause undefined behaviour (likely just a crash). That's not *wrong*, but if it is what you intend, you should document it, at the very least with a comment:

```
template <class T>
// expects !this->empty()
T& Stack<T>::top() const {
    return _top->data;
}
```

In C++20 you can use contracts:

```
template <class T>
T& Stack<T>::top() const
    [[ expects: !empty() ]]
{
    return _top->data;
}
```

But whatever you use, you really should document your code's behaviour and requirements.

```
template <class T>
void Stack<T>::pop() {
    if(_top == nullptr) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("the Stack is empty!");
    }
    do_unchecked_pop();
}
```

I'm not sure `invalid_argument` makes sense here... particularly given that there's no argument. This smells more like a job for `out_of_range`.

## Summary

- Add the necessary includes for the standard library facilities you use.
- Use in-class initializers for members that have sensible defaults. (Like pointers should almost always be set to `nullptr`.
- Mark all no-fail functions `noexcept`.
- Handle exceptions in the copy constructor - don't leak memory.
- Don't double-constructor your nodes; don't default construct `Node::data` then move/copy assign to it. Construct node data in place.
- Use more comments to document your code's intentions.

## Answers to questions

Apologies if some of this stuff is obvious to you - it's hard to gauge how much someone already knows. And anyway, even if it's obvious to you, it might help someone else reading this.

### Defaulted operations

There are a number of operations that the compiler generates for you implicitly. That includes the default constructor, the destructor, copy/move operations, and so on. Most of the time, you don't need to write anything at all. For example, if you do:

```
struct Foo {};

Foo f;
```

`Foo` will automatically have a default constructor, a destructor, and so on.

But sometimes you do something that *suppresses* the implicitly generated stuff. For example, any time you add a constructor to a class, it suppresses the default constructor.

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo(int) {}
};

Foo f; // won't compile, no default constructor
```

Because `Foo` has a constructor defined, the default constructor is suppressed.

If you want the default constructor back, you have to specifically request it:

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo(int) {}
    Foo() = default;
};

Foo f; // will compile
```

The `= default` just tells the compiler: "That function that you were going to generate until I did something to suppress it? Generate it anyway."

You could write `Foo() {}` instead of `Foo() = default;`, because that's basically what the compiler is going to do anyway. But there's an important difference:

- `Foo() {}` is ***NOT*** an implicitly-generated default constructor... it's a **user-defined default constructor** that just happens to do the same thing as the implicitly-generated default constructor.
- `Foo() = default;` ***IS*** an implicitly-generated default constructor.

They both do the same thing, but when a default constructor is actually compiler-generated, the compiler can do a lot more optimizing with it. So you (pretty much) *always* want to use `Foo() = default;`, and not `Foo() {}`.

So the question is: Where do you need to use it?

The answer is: Anywhere that an implicitly-generated function works for you, but it's somehow been suppressed.

In `Stack`, the default constructor works for you (once you use an in-class intiializer for `_top` to set it to `nullptr`). But it gets suppressed when you define the copy/move constructors. So you need `= default` to get it back again.

None of the other implicitly-generated functions work for you in `Stack` unfortunately, because of the rule of 5. You need a custom destructor and copy/move ops, so you can't just `= default` them.

### Free swap

The reason why you generally want a non-member swap function is because (as you know) the proper way to do a swap in C++ is this:

```
using std::swap;
swap(a, b);
```

That uses [argument-dependent lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) to dispatch to the correct swap function.

So if I do:

```
namespace indi {

struct Foo {};
void swap(Foo&, Foo&);

struct Bar {};

} // namespace indi
```

then:

```
using std::swap;

int i1, i2;
swap(i1, i2); // calls std::swap

indi::Foo f1, f2;
swap(f1, f2); // calls indi::swap

indi::Bar b1, b2;
swap(b1, b2); // calls std::swap
```

You can see that `std::swap()` gets used normally... but when there's a custom swap function, like for `Foo`, that gets used instead. The custom swap function must be in the same namespace as the class for this to work.

If your class is swappable, and you need a custom swap function, then you should almost always define a free swap function in the same namespace as your class. That allows a more efficient custom swap to be used when swapping is done correctly.

If you *don't* define a free swap function for `Stack`, then:

```
using std::swap;

Stack<int> s1, s2;
swap(s1, s2); // calls std::swap
```

will "work", because `Stack` is movable (which is all that `std::swap()` requires). But it will create a temporary `Stack` object and do three moves. Bit of a waste of time.

However, if you define:

```
template <typename T>
void swap(Stack<T>& a, Stack<T>& b) noexcept
{
    a.swap(b);
}
```

and put it in the same namespace that `Stack` is in, then:

```
using std::swap;

Stack<int> s1, s2;
swap(s1, s2); // now calls your custom swap (which does s1.swap(s2))
```

No temporary `Stack` objects get created, and the swap gets done as efficiently as possible.

In the case of `Stack`, you don't need to make the free swap function a friend, because it can just call the `swap()` member function, which is public:

```
template <typename T>
class Stack
{
public:
    void swap(Stack& other) noexcept;

    // ...
};

// Member function
template <typename T>
void Stack<T>::swap(Stack<T>& other) noexcept
{
    using std::swap;
    swap(_top, other._top);
}

// Free function
template <typename T>
void swap(Stack<T>& a, Stack<T>& b) noexcept
{
    a.swap(b);
}
```

That's cool. (Incidentally, as of C++20, both of those functions can also be `constexpr`! You *could* make them both `constexpr` before C++20 if you do the swap manually, without `std::swap()`. Whether that's worth it is up to you.)

However, if you didn't need a `swap()` member function, and you couldn't do the swap without access to hidden members, then you could make your free swap function a friend. But in `Stack`'s case, it's not necessary.

So the general rule is: If your type has a custom swap operation, define a free `swap()` function in the same namespace as the type.

(And since you almost always have to make a custom swap operation for any non-trivial type - if only so you can do moves properly, and use copy-and-swap for copying - you should almost always have a free `swap()` function for a class... even if all it does is call a member `swap()` function (as in `Stack`'s case).)

Comment: Thank you for answer, really appreciate that you thought it was decent code. I have been teaching myself C++. I may have a few questions with what you said but I will have to get back to you tomorrow. Do you mind if I ask some questions in regards to your answer tomorrow?

Comment: Not at all, ask any time.

Comment: Hi, sorry it took so long to comment, been busy with some stuff. My first question is pertaining to "You should always prefer to use = default rather than {} when defining things that can be implicitly generated, and the implicitly generated versions do the right thing." Is there any where else I need to use the = default? I never heard of it before.

Comment: Second, for the  free swap() function, where should I include it? In public: somewhere? Also is a free swap function when you cast it as a friend?

Comment: I'll answer these questions by extending the answer above, because some of them take a bit of explaining that won't fit in a comment.

Comment: Thank you, your answer was very very clear. Thanks again for you hard work.

Comment: I just finished a queue data structure which is similar to this so thought I would let you know: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/197607/generic-queue-data-structure-in-c

Answer (score 4):

Just adding to @indis answer.

## Copy constructor

The new, copied stack gets created in reverse. The object of was at the top of the old stack is now at the bottom of the stack of the copy.

Here a detailed look at how the copy gets constructed:

> ```
> original stack             copy
> [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]          []
>   ^
> ```

First, the top element of the original stack gets selected and `push`ed onto the new one.

> ```
> [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]          [ 1 ]
>      ^
> ```

Then, the next one gets selected and `push`ed onto the new stack.

> ```
> [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]          [ 2, 1 ]
>         ^
> ```

Wait, what happened? `push` inserted `2` at the front of the new stack. While this is usually the expected behavior of `push`, this isn't actually wanted here. To create a copy, the elements need be inserted at the back of the linked list, not the front.

So, how to fix this:

```
template <class T>
Stack<T>::Stack(Stack<T> const& value) : _top(nullptr) {
    // get the address of where the next node will be inserted
    auto insert_pos = &_top;

    for(auto loop = value._top; loop != nullptr; loop = loop->next) {
        // create new node
        auto copy_node = new node(loop->data);
        // insert node
        *insert_pos = copy_node;
        // save the next insertion address
        insert_pos = &copy_node->next;
    }
}
```

## `const` correctness

`top` returns a mutable reference while the stack itself is `const`, i.e. . This allows the modification of the internal state of a `const` object. Not good!

This can be fixed by removing the `const`, so the mutable reference only gets returned if the stack itself is mutable.

However, now the `top` element of a `const` stack can no longer be accessed. To fix this, we need a new overload of `top` for a `const` stack, that returns a `const T&` (to prevent modification).

So we get the final member function signatures

```
T& top();
const T& top() const;
```

## Memory management

I'd highly suggest you have a look at `std::unique_ptr`. While the implementation mostly keeps track of object lifetimes, it still doesn't handle all cases (like the memory leak in the copy constructor in case of an exception).

Using `std::unique_ptr` would help there, automatically destroying those objects. It would also simplify the pointer managing code a bit.

While smart pointers don't have to be used everywhere, they are a very important tool in the C++ toolbox. Especially if you are new to C++, try them out and add them to your repertoire, since they help to prevent so many bugs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just have two questions. First, for the copy constructor part, do I just need to reverse the for loop so that is starts from the back? Second, using std::unique_ptr would I still need the rule of 5? It seems like I would not since it automatically destroys the objects.

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx Re copy constructor: Going backwards through a singly linked list is not that easy (you'd need to somehow remember what came beforehand). It's easier to just keep track of where you need to insert the next node in the new stack. I'll add an example to the answer. // Re `unique_ptr` and Rule of 5: You'd still have a custom copy constructor/copy assignment operator, so Rule of 5 would recommend adding the other parts as well (even if it is `= default`). For a linked list I'd still recommend a manual cleanup in order to prevent stack overflow errors.

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx: Also, I just noticed that you grouped the default constructor under `// Rule of 5` instead of the copy assignment operator. Rule of 5 concerns itself with moving, copying and destroying objects.

Comment: I see,  I just said // Rule of 5 to show myself where all the constructors are. I know the rule of 5 concerns just the moving, copying and destroying of objects.

Comment: Oh wait, I dont have the rule of 5 correct? I thought I did have a custom copy constructor/copy assignment operator.

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx: You have it correct, just the comment is misplaced ;)

Comment: Okay great thanks. If you were to grade my code at this point out of 10 what would it be. I find it difficult to really evaluate my improvement as I continue teaching myself.

Comment: @Snorlaxx: Maybe from 3/10 to 6/10. I'm still missing `std::unique_ptr` (I cannot see any specific reason **not** to use them), and the "advanced options" I mentioned on the first question.

Comment: I did not include the std::unique_pointer because I wanted to practice memory management as I do not have as much practice of that. For the "advanced options" I honestly did not understand how to make those changes as of yet. Sigh, seems like my programming skills are still a bit lackluster...

Comment: Did you mean my grade was a 3/10 in the beginning and now its a 6/10? Or do you mean my grade as of now is between a 3-6 out of 10?

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx: I meant this code as presented was a 6/10. // Regarding manual memory management: It's really hard to get correct in all cases, and `std::unique_ptr` helps a lot in getting it done right. Every call to `new` is just a leak waiting to happen. In this particular piece of code, we might reasonably evaluate all possible lifetime issues (though I'm not sure I've got all of them!), but in slightly larger codebases some calls to `delete` will be missed. `std::unique_ptr` prevents that (though you have to be aware of the recursion issue).

Comment: Okay, so you suggest using unique_ptr for all that data structures? As in linked lists, stack, queue, vector, binary tree, graphs, hash table, etc...? If so, I will start to re-do all the data structures I have done so far. Do we still need the rule of 5 and destructor when we use unique_ptr?

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx: If you don't need custom behavior for copy/move construction and assignment, you can simply use default generated ones for those operations. But since most containers need custom copy constructors/assignment operators, you'll still be stuck with the rule of five, The compiler will only generate default copy and move constructors and assignment operators if none of those are otherwise defined. (Though you might be able to `= default` them.)