# Generic Queue data structure in C++

Tags: c++, queue

I am a mathematician attempting to become proficient with C++. At the moment I am learning about data structures. I am now writing a queue data structure using linked list from scratch.

I have tested my class that I wrote and everything seems to be working fine but I want to see if there are any bugs or some areas of the code I could improve on.

Here is the class:

```
#ifndef Queue_h
#define Queue_h

template <class T>
class Queue {
private:
    struct Node {
        T data;
        Node* next = nullptr;
    };
    Node* first = nullptr;
    Node* last = nullptr;

    // Used for destructor to delete elements
    void do_unchecked_pop();

    // Use for debugging purposes and for overloading the << operator
    void show(std::ostream &str) const;

public:
    // Constructors
    Queue() = default;                                                        // empty constructor
    Queue(Queue const& value);                                                // copy constructor

    // Rule of 5
    Queue(Queue&& move) noexcept;                                             // move constuctor
    Queue& operator=(Queue&& move) noexcept;                                  // move assignment operator
    ~Queue();                                                                 // destructor

    // Overload operators
    Queue& operator=(Queue const& rhs);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str, Queue<T> const& data) {
        data.show(str);
        return str;
    }

    // Member functions
    bool empty() const {return first == nullptr;}
    int size() const;
    T& front() const;
    T& back() const;
    void push(const T& theData);
    void push(T&& theData);
    void pop();
    void swap(Queue& other) noexcept;


};

template <class T>
Queue<T>::Queue(Queue<T> const& value)  {
    try {
        for(auto loop = value.first; loop != nullptr; loop = loop->next)
            push(loop->data);
    }
    catch (...) {
        while(first != nullptr)
            do_unchecked_pop();
        throw;
    }
}

template <class T>
Queue<T>::Queue(Queue&& move) noexcept {
    move.swap(*this);
}

template <class T>
Queue<T>& Queue<T>::operator=(Queue<T> &&move) noexcept {
    move.swap(*this);
    return *this;
}

template <class T>
Queue<T>::~Queue() {
    while(first != nullptr) {
        do_unchecked_pop();
    }
}

template <class T>
int Queue<T>::size() const {
    int size = 0;
    for (auto current = first; current != nullptr; current = current->next)
        size++;
    return size;
}

template <class T>
T& Queue<T>::front() const {
    if(first == nullptr) {
        throw std::out_of_range("the Queue is empty!");
    }
    return first->data;
}

template <class T>
T& Queue<T>::back() const {
    return last->data;
}

template <class T>
void Queue<T>::push(const T& theData) {
    Node* newNode = new Node;
    newNode->data = theData;
    newNode->next = nullptr;

    if(first == nullptr) {
        first = last = newNode;
    }

    else {
        last->next = newNode;
        last = newNode;
    }
}

template <class T>
void Queue<T>::push(T&& theData) {
    Node* newNode = new Node;
    newNode->data = std::move(theData);
    newNode->next = nullptr;

    if(first == nullptr) {
        first = last = newNode;
    }

    else {
        last->next = newNode;
        last = newNode;
    }
}

template <class T>
void Queue<T>::pop() {
    if(first == nullptr) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("the Queue is empty!");
    }
    do_unchecked_pop();
}

template <class T>
void Queue<T>::do_unchecked_pop() {
    Node* tmp = first->next;
    delete tmp;
    first = tmp;
}

template <class T>
void Queue<T>::show(std::ostream &str) const {
    for(Node* loop = first; loop != nullptr; loop = loop->next) {
        str << loop->data << "\t";
    }
    str << "\n";
}

template <class T>
void Queue<T>::swap(Queue<T> &other) noexcept {
    using std::swap;
    swap(first, other.first);
    swap(last, other.last);
}

// Free function
template <typename T>
void swap(Queue<T>& a, Queue<T>& b) noexcept {
    a.swap(b);
}


#endif /* Queue_h */
```

Here is the main.cpp that tests the latter class:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <iosfwd>
#include "Queue.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

      ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////// Queue Using Linked List //////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    Queue<int> obj;
    obj.push(2);
    obj.push(4);
    obj.push(6);
    obj.push(8);
    obj.push(10);
    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout<<"---------------Displaying Queue Contents---------------";
    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout << obj << std::endl;

    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout<<"---------------Pop Queue Element -------------------";
    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    obj.pop();
    std::cout << obj << std::endl;

    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout<<"---------------Get the size of Queue -------------------";
    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout << obj.size() << std::endl;


    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout<<"---------------Print top element --------------------";
    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout << obj.front() << std::endl;

    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout<<"---------------Print last element --------------------";
    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout << obj.back() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just looking at the beginning of the class, I can see that you’ve learned a lot since your first version.  Keep it up!

---

As I’ve said before, Don’t make explicit comparisons against `nullptr`. Use the contextual conversion to bool as a truth value.

---

```
    while(first != nullptr)
        do_unchecked_pop();
```

is repeated.  You should have a single helper function to delete a whole list, if you are avoiding deep recursion.  If your list is small you don’t need it at all as it should already take care of itself.

---

You have several loops of the form

```
for(auto loop = value.first; loop != nullptr; loop = loop->next)
```

you should provide proper iterators so you can just use a range-`for`

---

[Prefer using `\n` over `std::endl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n)

The style in C++ is to put the `*` or `&` with the *type*, not the identifier.  This is called out specifically near the beginning of Stroustrup’s first book, and is an intentional difference from C style.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am glad you can see improvement in my programming. For the explicit comparison against nullptr, instead can I just my empty() function instead? So essentially, !empty() instead of first != nullptr.

Comment: `!empty()` — Even better!

Comment: for the do_unchecked_pop() could that code be applied for deleteTail() for a single linked list or no?

Comment: To delete a list, you do not need to use recursion — just use a `while` loop.

Comment: I meant deleting a tail not a list. Could we use unchecked_pop() to delete a tail in a single linked list?

Comment: Your `do_unchecked_pop` function is written to look specifically at the head.  I don’t know what you are asking.

Answer (score 4):

There is a check missing in your `back()` function (If the queue is empty you have an error).

It would increase readability if you  would use `empty()` instead of repeated `top == nullptr` checks. The intent is more obvious that way.

Your `do_unchecked_pop` is buggy

```
template <class T>
void Queue<T>::do_unchecked_pop() {
    Node* tmp = first->next;
    delete tmp;
    first = tmp;
}
```

You assign first to the deleted node. I think you would want to delete first here not tmp.

In you `push()` function there is no need to assign next to nullptr as it is already the default value. However, it would definitely improve readability if you would simply create a constructor for `Node`

Comment: Are you saying to just change delete tmp to delete first?

Comment: Exactly, you want to delete the head of the queue not the second element